# Tensorflow error on mamp server

Tags: python, tensorflow

**I can run these codes on editor but when i tried to run on mamp server i got this error**

> type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named tensorflow
>
> > args = ('No module named tensorflow',)
> >
> > > ```
> > >  message = 'No module named tensorflow'"
> > > ```

Here is my HTML codes

```
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.cgi" method="post">
<p>File: <input type="file" name="file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My python codes are too long so i upload these to web

### My python codes' link : https://paste.ee/p/5q8xV#s=0

### [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5fMg.png)

I need help immediately please help me

Comment: How did you install `tensorflow`?

Comment: I installed with following the steps from [there](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like TensorFlow is installed on your local machine but not your server.

[Installing TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/)

Comment: I am using MAMP server.Do i need install tensorflow to my MAMP server?.If so how can i install tensorflow to my MAMP server?

Comment: @SerhatTurkmen I'm assuming your MAMP server is running MacOS so follow the Mac installation instructions described in the 'Installing TensorFlow' link. If you don't have access to install stuff then you're probably out of luck

Comment: I already install tensorflow like this i can run tensorflow on editor but i cant on server what do you suggest for me ?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you've installed TensorFlow on your local computer but not your server, if you have CLI access you can easily just install TensorFlow on the server.